# Ещё раз о слове "осиянный"

Tags: причастия, нн

Задавал вопрос о краткой форме этого слова давно, но он куда-то исчез. :(

По запросу в Интернете везде написано, что это ***причастие***. Но почему краткая форма от него *"осия**нн**а", "осия**нн**о",* то есть *с НН и ударением на **я***? Ведь в подобных случаях обычно бывает *одна Н и ударение на последний слог!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Толковый словарь Ожегова**

ОСИЯ́ННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -ян, -янна (**устар. высок.**). Освещённый, озарённый. Лунным светом осиянные поля.

> **Вопрос № 280362**
>
> Здравствуйте! Скажите, как правильно поставить ударение в слове "осияна"? ОсиЯна? Или всё же осиянА? Спасибо заранее!
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: **осиЯнна.**

Это слово **высокого стиля**, оно сохраняет изначальную краткую форму ***осиЯнна***. В современном языке такая форма характерна для прилагательного.

Вероятно, раньше оно использовалась и как **прилагательное** (какова? ― осиянна), и как **причастие** (осиянна чем?), но эти формы были одинаковыми. Такая ситуация сохраняется и сейчас.

*Но забыли мы, что **осиянно**

Только слово средь земных тревог...*
[О. Э. Мандельштам. О природе слова (1921-1922)]

*Она **осиянна** особливым Божественным **светом***... [архиепископ Платон (Левшин). (1777)]

Не думаю, что попытки использовать форму причастия будут успешными.

[словоформы слова "осиянная"](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Да, интересное слово. ;)

Comment: Да, красивое слово, но в наше время используется редко. А вам  спасибо за такое красивое оформление ответа. Я тоже хотела перейти от ссылки к названию, но не знаю как.

Comment: Да не за что!) На панели есть кнопка, третья слева, рядом с кавычками. Или просто нажимаете ctrl L. Но сначала надо написать текст и его выделить. А как нажмёте на эту кнопку или сочетание клавиш, появится поле для ссылки (заранее копируйте её и потом вставляйте).

Comment: Спасибо, потренируюсь.